# Did Allah (Swt) reveal the Quran to Jibril (as) in Arabic?

Tags: quran, revelation

Assalamu Alaikum Brothers in Islam,

The Holy Qur'an is the Eternal Speech of Allah. It was revealed to the Beloved prophet Muhammed (saw) in Arabic through the Angel Jibril (as).

So there's a question that has been troubling me. 
Did Allah reveal the Qur'an to Jibril (as) in arabic also? Or Did Allah reveal the Qur'an to Jibril (as) in a way that befits His majesty and then Jibril(as) revealed the Qur'an to Prophet muhammed (saw) in Arabic?

What is the stance of Ahl sunnah wal jamaah on this issue?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: Salaam Insaan... just curious ... how does this query help you increase your imaan in any way? Wouldn't the Prophet (SAW) have informed the Sahaba if it would have been helpful for the Ummah?